# Show repeating Notification from some start Date until some end date

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-alarms

I have many weekly-repeating events every one has a start/End dates.
it should appear every week at the same day & time.

So I want to show notification for every event on every week at a specific date&time starting from it's start Date until it's end date.

Can any one provide me with a tutorial / explanation / Links on how to implement this, please?

Comment: Basically android has an OS service that checks for any notification directed to the device thats running it. As a developer you have to send the message to google's servers which in turn will send it to the devices corresponding to your users. However you wish to time your notification pushes is a different story. Check out the documentation for [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Comment: @MrD, Thanks but I don't think I need to use that Cloud Messaging Service as the App is local and Events data are saved to a local sqlite DB. I just want to learn how to show these notifications correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do unless you want to have some service running in the background of your client's devices which would probably be a bad idea as it'd waste a lot of battery and other resources. I don't know if theres any other way around it tho.

Comment: Actually, I am just coding that App for learning only, So I think it is okay if I Learned how to deal with the local background services and maybe later I would learn that FCM service.

Comment: You might find [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WozSRUnYoNM&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvSPjWpLPFEfOCbezi6vATIh&index=21) tutorial helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the official Android docs - link [here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

You need to use the `setRepeating` function in `AlarmManager` to achieve this. Create a `BroadcastReceiver` that creates a notification when an `Intent` is received. Set this `Intent` in a `PendingIntent` and give the `PendingIntent` to the `AlarmManager#setRepeating`.

Example code -

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```